# Metronic | KeenThemes Charts not working Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, metronic

I followed to the following tutorial :

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=laravel-integration

Theme installation is successful.
Except for one thing. The charts are not showing up.

[Here a screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleNS.png)

The assets were successfully downloaded and compiled. Here is the package.js content.

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^11.2.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "^12.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon-block": "^12.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^12.4.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline": "^12.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/google-calendar": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.2.0",
    "@uppy/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@uppy/progress-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "@uppy/tus": "^1.2.0",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^2.23.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "autosize": "^4.0.0",
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "bootstrap-datetime-picker": "^2.4.4",
    "bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^0.0.7",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-maxlength": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.13.10",
    "bootstrap-switch": "3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "bootstrap-touchspin": "^4.2.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "corejs-typeahead": "^1.3.0",
    "counterup": "^1.0.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.6",
    "datatables.net-autofill-bs4": "^2.3.4",
    "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs4": "^1.6.0",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs4": "^1.5.2",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4": "^3.3.0",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4": "^3.1.6",
    "datatables.net-keytable-bs4": "^2.5.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs4": "^2.2.3",
    "datatables.net-rowgroup-bs4": "^1.1.1",
    "datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4": "^1.2.6",
    "datatables.net-scroller-bs4": "^2.0.1",
    "datatables.net-select-bs4": "^1.3.1",
    "dompurify": "^1.0.9",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
    "dual-listbox": "1.1.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "es6-promise-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "flot": "^3.2.2",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
    "handlebars": "4.1.0",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.6",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "jkanban": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-form": "^4.2.2",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-validation": "1.19.0",
    "jquery.repeater": "^1.2.1",
    "jqvmap": "^1.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jstree": "^3.3.8",
    "jszip": "^3.2.2",
    "markdown": "^0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "nouislider": "^13.1.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.60",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "prismjs": "^1.8.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "select2": "^4.0.8",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "sticky-js": "^1.2.0",
    "stream-exhaust": "^1.0.2",
    "summernote": "0.8.12",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.0.6",
    "tagify": "^0.1.1",
    "tether": "^1.4.3",
    "tinymce": "^5.0.16",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uppy": "^1.3.0",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "wnumb": "^1.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Can you see any error in the console?